# Karma does not execute e2e tests when :run is added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

i am using Grunt,Angular and Karma and I have a following problem- I read that i have to add ":run" to the name of the karma task in order to run all the tests on the background and use only one instance of Karma. Sounds nice and easy. It works with unit tests, but it just does not work when i try the same thing with e2e tests. For some reason I am getting:

```
Running "karma:e2e:run" (karma) task
NOT FOUND
```

When i remove ":run" then i am getting a new Chrome window every time the tests are triggered.

relevant parts of my gruntfile looks like this:

```
karma : {
  e2e : {
    configFile : 'src/config/karma-e2e.conf.js',
    background : true
  },      
  unit : {
    configFile : 'src/config/karma.conf.js',
    background : true
  }
},

watch : {
  scripts : {
    files : ["src/app/*.coffee", "src/partials/*.html","src/*.html","src/styl/*.styl"],
    tasks : ['nah'],
    options : {
      spawn : false,
      livereload: true
    }
  }
}

grunt.registerTask('nah', ['stylus','coffeelint','coffee','concat','karma:unit:run','karma:e2e:run','watch']);
```

My Karma config looks like:

```
module.exports = function(config){
config.set({

    basePath : '../',

    files : [
        '../test/e2e/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : false,

    //singleRun : true,

    reporters : 'dots',

    frameworks : ['ng-scenario'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    proxies : {
      '/': 'http://localhost:3000/src/'
    },

    urlRoot : '/__e2e/',

    plugins : [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-ng-scenario'
            ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
      suite: 'e2e'
    }

});
};
```

I am not really sure what is NOT FOUND and how to fix it and since i have been googling and messing around with it without any results i have decided to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: did you try karma:unit instead of karma:unit:run?

Comment: Yeah, karma:unit:run works but karma:e2e:run does not so karma:unit:run is not the problem at all. According to this: https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma you should add ":run" to all of your karma tasks when you are running Karma on background.

Comment: I also failed to run e2e scenario with karma. This is why I tried [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and decided to use it for e2e tests.

Comment: I have been playing with it for 3 days now and still nothing. I am starting to get furious...